# How do I set the levels in a dataset using the model data structure from bnlearn?

Tags: r, classification, bayesian-networks

I'm trying to use models from the bnlearn package in R to do classifier predictions, but with some datasets, some ofthe variable values (levels) are rarely seen, which means that the test data partition may not have all of the values for variable represented in the data file.

When using predict() with the bn model on this type of data set, an error message similar to the following is returned:

> : In check.data(data) :   variable V3 has levels that are not observed
>   in the data.

I would like to reset the levels in the model similar to the method here:

[Error in bn.fit predict function in bnlear R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30598739/error-in-bn-fit-predict-function-in-bnlear-r)

but I don't have access to the original data, just the model.

So, how do I get the number of levels from the bn data structure to set the number of levels in the data set to be predicted?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the question is asking the wrong thing. After quite a bit of poring over the code, the answer lies in a function, check.data, used to verify the data for both the learning and the predicting phases, which is, in this case, non-sensical. The correct answer is to modify bnlearn to eliminate this bug.

Comment: And for an even more detailed answer. Have a look here: https://informationentropy.wordpress.com/2015/11/11/knime-and-r-integration-with-unbalanced-classes-in-test-and-train-partitions/